# How do I detect if more than 2 players are online with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft **1.14.4**, I and my friend want to make a custom map and we need to detect if there are at least 2 players online with command blocks.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @pppery That answer is outdated and uses `testfor`, and this person wants to know how to do it in 1.14.

Comment: @cherryblossom Questions with outdated answers to not cease to be valid duplicate targets.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using scoreboards.
In an impulse command block put this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add playercount dummy "playercounter"
```

Then connect 4 chain command blocks set to always active, in the first one put this command:

```
/execute as @a run scoreboard players add x playercount 1
```

___________________________Second__________________________________

```
/execute if score x playercount matches 2.. run *"your command here"*
```

____________________________Third________________________________

```
/execute if score x playercount matches ..2 run tellraw @a {"text":"There are not enough players","color":"red"}
```

_________________________Fourth__________________________________

```
/scoreboard players reset x playercount
```